# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver DLE - Visionflow Program to mysql -DLESessionConfig.xml

Tags: mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I am having problem connecting to MySQL from JDBC Java Database Connectivity.
I have tried to write Property to connect to MySQL from DLESessionconfig.xml
Something like this:

```xml
<Property name="JDBCDriver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />        
<Property name="JDBCURL" value="jdbc:mysql://172.16.100.41:3306/verladen" />
```

However, it seems something is missing, I am not sure it is problem with Driver?

```
Exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)    at.visionflow.dle.engine.connectors.DefaultJDBCConnectionFactory.getConnection(DefaultJDBCConnectionFactor
```

[Configfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8s3c.png)

Comment: It doesn't seem like drivers is in your classpath? Do you use maven?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not use Maven. But you are right about drivers, there is no jar files for mysql and i have installed it. After making sure compactible jdbc driver version for mysql 8, my program works.